# Importing obj and obj.mtl files in Maya

Tags: rendering, maya

I have a mesh model in a .ply file, I have converted it to an obj and obj.mtl (material) file using an online converter (http://www.greentoken.de/onlineconv/). When I load the obj file into maya I see none of the texture being rendered. I've done some googling and this seems like a common problem, but am yet to find a solution.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Does your mtl file include references to your textures? And if so, are they referenced as filenames only or by path?  If they are only file names they'll need to be in the same folder as your obj file for maya to find them

Comment: Do you have texture coordinates in your .ply file, or it is instead colored using vertex colors? If so, you will have to generate UV coordinates for the OBJ file to show any texture

Answer (score 0):

Check the texture file paths in your mtl file path. If they have path separators, make sure they are forward slashes not back slashes. For some reason if they are back slashes, the parent directory name will be inserted over the filename and a space when Maya parses them into the File node 'Image Name' field.

e.g. This filepath in the mtl:

```
map_Ka textures\vase_round.tga
```

will become this in the Maya File node:

```
textures nd.tga
```